# Unable to see whole pdf content after indexing pdf file in ES

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin

Below is my code to index a pdf url in Elasticsearch:

```
import requests
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch
es = Elasticsearch()
body = {
     "description" : "Extract attachment information",
     "processors" : [
        {
            "attachment" : {
            "field" : "data"
        }
      }
 ]
}
es.index(index='_ingest', doc_type='pipeline', id='attachment', body=body)
url = 'https://pubs.vmware.com/nsx-63/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/nsx_63_cross_vc_install.pdf'
response = requests.get(url)
import base64

data = base64.b64encode(response.content).decode('ascii')
 result2 = es.index(index='my_index', doc_type='my_type', pipeline='attachment',
              body={'data': data})
 result2
 doc = es.get(index='my_index', doc_type='my_type', id=result2['_id'],   _source_exclude=['data'])
 doc
 print(doc['_source']['attachment']['content'])
```

Last line is printing the contents of pdf file till 63 page only out of 126.
Do I need to change any settings somewhere(already tried to increase the console o/p,dint helped).

Please provide pointers on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a limit of `100000` characters extracted.
You can change it in the pipeline definition by setting `indexed_chars`.

See https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/plugins/current/using-ingest-attachment.html